# Intense of liner polarized wave: with a polarizer vs. without a polarizer differences

Tags: waves, polarization

We had this experiment in which we measured the intense of **linear polarized** wave - with and without a polarizer.

I noticed that **without the polarizer** the intense was slightly lower than **with the polarizer**. How is that possible?

[image]

The wave length was about 2.8 [cm].

With polarizer I got 0.317 [Volt] .
Without polarizer I got 0.2835 [Volt].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that your polarizer interacts with the other parts of your setup (for example, forms a resonant cavity with some other interfaces that enhances transmission). You can test this hypothesis by rotating your polarizer (is the intensity always brighter?). If you include a drawing of your setup, it would be easier to figure out the underlying reason.

Comment: If you turn off your source, is there any reading on your detector? (i.e. the polarizer might reflect microwave into your detector)

Comment: Unfortunately I did not measure it. If it helps when I rotated the polarizer 90 [deg] (from the position that gave me max intensity) I got 0.022 [Volt], do you think it has the same effedct as turning the source off?

Comment: The background radiation might also be polarized. I think such a measurement would be revealing.

Comment: So I want to refine your answer - it can be as a result of resonance, or maybe due to reflected waves that returned from the polarizer?

Comment: Yes, the seemingly strange phenomenon has to come from interaction with other things in your setup, unless the polarizer is a gain medium for microwaves, which is probably not the case here.